# Create a new kafka topic using python from a container connecting to another container

Tags: python, docker, apache-kafka, tcp, kafka-python

I would like to create a new kafka topic using python, and I get an error when I try to create a KafkaAdminClient using `server="kafka:9092"`:

```
self._kafka_admin = KafkaAdminClient(
                         bootstrap_servers=[server],
                         api_version=(0, 10, 2),
                         api_version_auto_timeout_ms=120000)
```

The error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 47, in <module>
    kafka_manager = KafkaManager("kafka:9092") 
  File "/app/src/kafka/kafka_manager.py", line 24, in __init__
    self._kafka_admin = KafkaAdminClient(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kafka/admin/client.py", line 211, in __init__
    self._client.check_version(timeout=(self.config['api_version_auto_timeout_ms'] / 1000))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kafka/client_async.py", line 900, in check_version
    raise Errors.NoBrokersAvailable()
kafka.errors.NoBrokersAvailable: NoBrokersAvailable
```

Moreover, I've build the next docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  spark-master:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:2
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=master
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./conf/log4j.properties
        target: /opt/bitnami/spark/conf/log4j.properties
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
      - '7077:7077'
    networks:
      - spark
    container_name: spark
  spark-worker-1:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:2
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://localhost:7077
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1G
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./conf/log4j.properties
        target: /opt/bitnami/spark/conf/log4j.properties
    ports:
      - '8081:8081'
    container_name: spark-worker
    networks:
      - spark
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    ports:
      - 22181:2181
    container_name: zookeeper
    networks: 
      - rmoff_kafka
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.5.0
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    container_name: kafka
    networks: 
      - rmoff_kafka
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
    depends_on: 
      - kafka
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    container_name: app
    networks: 
      - rmoff_kafka

networks:
  spark:
    driver: bridge
  rmoff_kafka:
    name: rmoff_kafka
```

Finally, the structure is something like this, 2 containers (1 for python app, another 1 for kafka):
[image]

And the `docker ps` result to see the details of the containers:
[image]

Comment: Check your logs to see if your Python app is starting faster than the broker. And again, you don't need both Spark and Python containers to work with Kafka from an app

Comment: Worked! Thanks a lot, the problem was the host name which has to be the name of the container and adding an sleep() command in python in order to wait for the kafka container to start.

Comment: Feel free to put your solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was changing the host name to the name of the container (kafka), and adding an sleep() command in python in order to wait for the kafka container to start.